# Can I get programmatic access to ulimit and sysctl.conf vars in Python?

Tags: python, linux

I'd like to verify that a large number of Linux hosts are set up correctly. Currently I can do this by grepping sysctl.conf and executing commands like ulimit:

```
[username@hostname ~]$ tail -2 /etc/sysctl.conf
fs.file-max = 65536
vm.max_map_count = 262144
[username@hostname ~]$ ulimit -u
4096
```

I'd like to write a script to gather all the following data:

- Maximum file descriptors
- Max threads
- Max map count

Sure, I can get this by automating my manual process, but is there a more programmatic way of getting this data in Python? I'd rather know what the OS reports the value as, and not what's in the config file - just in case there's a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two locations you can get this information:

- for `ulimit` information, use the [`resource` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/resource.html); the process limit is the `resource.RLIMIT_NPROC` constant.

  ```
  import resource

  nproc_soft, nproc_hard = resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NPROC)
  ```
- For reading current `sysctl.conf` values, read the `/proc/sys` filesystem. The options in `sysctl.conf` map one-on-one to paths in that system, just replace `.` with a path separator:

  ```
  # read the current setting for fs.file-max
  with open('/proc/sys/fs/file-max') as f:
      file_max = int(f.read())

  # thread count limit, kernel.threads-max
  with open('/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max') as f:
      threads_max = int(f.read())

  # map count limit, vm.max_map_count
  with open('/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count') as f:
      max_map_count = int(f.read())
  ```